# How to get absolute min of vectors spread intermittently throughout matrix?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that primarily has individual values, but occasionaly there are bound lists within a single datapoint. I would like to change these columns to only inlcuding the absolute minimum value (retaining the sign).

```
     a     b        c     d         e     f
1    0.3   0.1      NA    c(-0.1,   0.2   0.2
                            0.9)    
2    0.1   c(0.1,   -0.3  0.05      NA    -0.1
             0.4)
```

So value **2,b would be 0.1**, and value **1,d would be -0.1**, and all other values would be unchanged.

This is what I have come up with so far

```
df <- df %>% mutate (across(!1, ~if_else(length(.x) > 1, df[.x][which.min(abs(df[.x]))], #do nothing)))
```

I have a few issues here however.

1. all of the values are changed, so It seems that length (.x) > 1 must not be working
2. I do not know how to have it retain the original values if false (ie if false, do nothing)
3. df[which.min(abs(df))] is also, not working, but I think this is mainly because I am not sure how to specifically index each value (which I think may be a root of my problem

Comment: what is the class of those list columns? `class(df$b)` or `class(df$d)` ?

Comment: The class is list

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b,            ~c,   ~d,             ~e,  ~f,
  0.3,           0.1,   NA, c(-0.1,0.9), 0.2, 0.2,
  0.1, c(0.1,0.4), -0.3,           0.05,  NA,  -0.1
)

df[] <- lapply(df, function(col) sapply(col, function(cell) ifelse(length(cell)==1, cell, min(unlist(cell)))))
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>       a     b     c     d     e     f
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   0.3   0.1  NA   -0.1    0.2   0.2
#> 2   0.1   0.1  -0.3  0.05  NA    -0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hmm, oddly this is not working, the columns with c() are still present.

Comment: Please can you provide `dput(df)` @JVDeasyas123?

Comment: unfortunately I can not for the actual dataset, as it cannot be shared publically. Happy to provide other information that may be helpful though

Comment: Well, with the data you shared, it does work as you can see above. It is difficult to help further if you cannot provide an example to reproduce what doesn't work. @JVDeasyas123

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `map_dbl` inside `across` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-1, function(x) map_dbl(x, ~.x[which.min(abs(.x))[1]])))

#    a   b    c     d   e    f
#1 0.3 0.1   NA -0.10 0.2  0.2
#2 0.1 0.1 -0.3  0.05  NA -0.1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(0.3, 0.1), b = list(0.1, c(0.1, 0.4)), c = c(NA, 
-0.3), d = list(c(-0.1, 0.9), 0.05), e = c(0.2, NA), f = c(0.2, 
-0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried to apply this to my dataset, and I recieve this error ```Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"```

Comment: Actually, this was the error ``` Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x non-numeric argument to mathematical function
i Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.```

Comment: That looks like a matrix object and not dataframe. What is `class(df)` ? Try using `df <- as.data.frame(df)` to convert to dataframe first.